# Android : Radio Buttons keep changing their state when List View Scrolled

Tags: android, radiobuttonlist, radio-group

I have a listview with three Radio Buttons in a list item, Issue is that when I scroll list view, the radio buttons selected position gets changed. So please let me know how to keep radio button's selection intact even if I scroll list view. My code is,

RadioGroupAdapter.java

```
public RadioGroupAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            Option[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        MatrixHolder holder = null;



        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new MatrixHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.heading);
            holder.group = (RadioGroup) row.findViewById(R.id.radio_group1);
            final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[2];
            for(int i=0; i<2; i++){

                rb[i]  = new RadioButton(context);
               // rb[i].setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.single_radio_chice);
                rb[i].setId(i);
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                        0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.weight=1.0f;
                params.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 10);
                holder.group.addView(rb[i],params); //the RadioButtons are added to the radioGroup instead of the layout
            }


           // ((MatrixHolder)holder).group.clearCheck();


            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (MatrixHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Option option = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(option.title);
        return row;
    }
```

Comment: SOLVED PREOBLEM BY ADDING TWO FUNCTIONS:

Answer (score 10):

Solved my problem by adding two different functions:
I know its almost a hack but it works. So never mind ;)

```
@Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {                 
                  //Count=Size of ArrayList.
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }
```

Comment: overriding these two functions will let the adapter know how many items there are and what their positions are
great job

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

Check out [Listview with RadioButtons](http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-listview-with-radiogroup.html) It may help you to solve your issue.

Comment: @GrlsHu: I checked your link. Its the same except that I am generating radio buttons and list items dynamically. Link shows us the static way to doing the same.

Comment: Checkout similar post also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842599/android-radio-buttons-in-a-custom-listview-changes-its-state-when-we-scroll-the

Comment: Didn't helped. Any other solution for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Map<Integer, <Value>>` then put your checked radio items in it. Key is listview's item positions. Value; your radio button view value.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my `listview` Items contained a `radiogroup` with the 3 `radioButtons` and this is how I solved the problem

First, I declared 3 maps for my 3 rows (Containing radio buttons 1, 2, 3)

```
private static Map<Integer, Boolean> firstRow = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
private static Map<Integer, Boolean> secondRow = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
private static Map<Integer, Boolean> thirdRow = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
```

Radio Group onCheckedCangedListener:

```
group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.opt1:
                if(!firstRow.containsKey(pstn)){
                    firstRow.put(pstn, true);
                    secondRow.remove(pstn);
                    thirdRow.remove(pstn);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.opt2:
                if(!secondRow.containsKey(pstn)){
                    secondRow.put(pstn, true);
                    firstRow.remove(pstn);
                    thirdRow.remove(pstn);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.opt3:
                if(!thirdRow.containsKey(pstn)){
                    thirdRow.put(pstn, true);
                    secondRow.remove(pstn);
                    firstRow.remove(pstn);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Finally, Updating the Radio buttons checked state:

```
if(firstRow.containsKey(position)){
    r1.setChecked(firstRow.get(position));
}
if(secondRow.containsKey(position)){
    r2.setChecked(secondRow.get(position));
}
if(thirdRow.containsKey(position)){
    r3.setChecked(thirdRow.get(position));
}
```